# Apache Spark - Speed malfuncition read.csv()

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I'm trying to perform machine learning on a 20 GB dataset which is in `.csv` format.
One of the things that is advertised about spark is the speed. I'm a bit new to spark.
In a pyspark environment if I simple perform a `spark.read.csv(file.csv)` it takes about 5 seconds on NFS and 1.5 seconds over HDFS. The problem with this the headers are labeled _C1, _C2, _C3, instead of using the actual headers of the dataset.
So I thought I'd try the following to get the dataset to read:

```
spark.read.csv(headers= "true", inferSchema="true", path= file.csv)
```

the dataframe provides the appropriate schemas, however this takes 10 minutes over NFS and longer on HDFS which is slower than Pandas. Is there a configuration setting I need to set to make it go faster.
I've tried this datasets on a dask environment which takes only 4 seconds and the dask dataframe provides all the appropriate labels and headers, but my memory card doesn't have enough memory to load all the data which is why I can't use this option.

Comment: According to the [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.csv), it requires a pass over the data to run with `inferSchema="true"`. Can you provide the schema up-front? Also, curious why you're not able to use dask? Dask performs lazy evaluation across a cluster so you shouldn't need to load al the data into memory

Comment: Spark is fast because it's distributed. You mentioned memory card which makes me think its an IOT device and it could be that spark doesn't fit your usecase

Comment: Dask does *not* require you to load all of the data into memory at once.

Comment: if you don't want to create schema manually, I usually use following "hack" - use sample file with data with several lines of data, load it with `inferSchema="true"`, obtain schema from resulting dataframe, and then use that schema when reading CSV file (via `schema=...` parameter)